# Bash script to send notification when a new data is added

Tags: database, bash, shell, db2

I need to work on a bash script to monitor the user table and sends a notification email to the sales team containing the newly created username.

I am new to scripting and have a little idea on how to do that.

appreciate any help or instructions.

Comment: I can suggest that you read [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html) and [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). And always refer to the [Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) / (`man bash`). `help` and `help <builtin_name>` is also a friend. You can post your script later when you find the task already too difficult for you.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged the question as DB2, in that RDBS you can create a trigger that send a message by email. You do not need bash in this case.

Let's suppose you have a table called users, and each time a new row is inserted, an email message will be sent.

```
CREATE or replace trigger t1
  after insert on users
  REFERENCING NEW AS N
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_sender VARCHAR(30);
  DECLARE v_recipients VARCHAR(60);
  DECLARE v_subj VARCHAR(20);
  DECLARE v_msg VARCHAR(200);

  SET v_sender = 'kkent@mycorp.com';
  SET v_recipients = 'bwayne@mycorp.com,pparker@mycorp.com';
  SET v_subj = 'New user';
  SET v_msg = 'There is a new user: ' || n.username;
  CALL UTL_MAIL.SEND(v_sender, v_recipients, NULL, NULL, v_subj, v_msg);
END@
```

You have to configure DB2 with your SMTP server and other parameters: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055176.html

Comment: Can you please provide more information on this? any example or link would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I did some searching yet still not sure how to send an email using trigger

Comment: Let's suppose a "new user" means a new row in the table (I updated the answer with an example). If you want to monitor the creation of "a new user with authorization to connect to the database", you cannot do that from DB2, but checking your authentication system (/etc/passwd or LDAP)

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use the `inotify` tool to detect the file modification and use the `mail` tool to send the mail in you script, as for how to use the command, please refers to the specific documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To send an email you could use gmail + `mutt`.  Just follow [this](http://www.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/consolify-your-gmail-with-mutt/) tutorial to see how to configure `mutt`.

Once mutt is configured, you can send email from a script using a command like this one:

```
echo "$BODY" | mutt -s "$SUBJECT" $EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

An example would be:

```
echo "User Bob has been added." | mutt -s "New User" example@example.com
```

You could also consider using [prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com/) to send push notifications to an IOS device.  [Prowl has a perl script](http://www.prowlapp.com/faq.php#script) that can be executed from your bash script.  This would provide near instant notification.  Prowl can also prioritize notifications.